# MapView sorted by title annotations are changed when adding to map annotations array

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary, annotations, mkmapview

I have a branch object array which are displayed on a picker view and I have created annotations according to these branches array details. I sorted both branches array and map view annotations according to title and I display them on the map view. And every time I choose from the picker view a branch, map zooms in to the correct branch annotation and shows the callout.

My main issue is that the branches are sorted correctly according to title but map annotations are never correctly sorted. Adding the `sortedAnnotation` to the `mapView.addAnnotations` changes the sorting.

```swift
let sortedAnnotations = mapView.annotations.sorted { rhs, lhs in
    if let rhsAnn = rhs.title, let rhsTitle = rhsAnn, let lhsAnn = lhs.title, let lhsTitle = lhsAnn {
        return rhsTitle < lhsTitle
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

mapView.addAnnotations(sortedAnnotations)

mapView.showAnnotations(mapView.annotations, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting data source of `addAnnotations` will make no difference as placement of the annotations depends on the coordinate not title

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This means that I will have to sort the branches array according to the coordinates too? But how can I sort an array according to lat and long.